# jQuery data() support in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-data

I have the following code;

```
dataObj = $(data).data();
```

Now here "data" represents a Div or DOM element to which I have some data attributes (or object) attached..

Thus $(data).data() works fine in all browsers (including IE9)...But not in IE7..

Is there some workaround for this?

Comment: Is it XHTML document?

Comment: The doctype i have used is <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: i've tested on IE7 emulated and works for me. Have you got error or empty object?

Comment: What is the jQuery version?

Comment: jQuery version is 1.9...It does not give any error in IE7...but does not return any data like in other browsers...

Comment: And what give you: `alert($(data).attr('data-mydata'));` , undefined or expected value?

Comment: That returns the actual value...But I would want to avoid doing this...since I have attached a complete object to my DOM elements...

Comment: For now I can only say, I confirm the existence of this problem in the same environment. I've even tested on various DOCTYPEs: HTML5, HTML4 Strict and HTML4 Transitional.

Comment: So it is not data attributes that you are using but the data() object. Sorry but i don't where your problem come from

Comment: Any help?? It is the data() which is not working in IE7...Does it depend on how it is implemented...like I have not directly coded data attribute in my HTML but through some jQuery/JSON bindings...